# Setting-up localhost to other desired name on WAMP 2.4.9 server gets 404 Error

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I want to rename my localhost server to other name, however I have encountered a 404 error. I have followed the steps how to set this up, But still I get error. I wonder what's wrong. I will provide the changes done.

c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts.file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   bluescript.com.ph

::89    localhost
::89    bluescript.com.ph
```

c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhost.conf
I added the third host on the file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName bluescript.com.ph
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/bluescript/"
  <Directory "c:/wamp/www/bluescript/">
      Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Under httpd.conf i did changed my port to 8989, since skype will use port 80

```
ServerName localhost:8989

#Listen 12.34.56.78:8989
Listen 0.0.0.0:8989
Listen [::0]:8989
```

I've already restarted WAMP and re-open the web browser and type url: http://bluescript.com.ph and get error: HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a non standard port number of Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove these dummy (Example) Virtual Hosts that point to non existing folders

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

2)
If you must use a Non-Standard port number for Apache then that port number needs to be on the Virtual Host as well.

You should also add a Virtual Hosts for localhost

```
<VirtualHost *:8989>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8989>
  ServerName bluescript.com.ph
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/bluescript/"
  <Directory "c:/wamp/www/bluescript/">
      Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also remember to remove the comment from `httpd.conf` to activate the httpd-`vhosts.conf` file

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

> Now restart Apache

And of course this means you must use the Non-Standard port number on all your urls. Like

> http://bluescript.com.ph:8989

3)
Also this is wrong in your hosts file! Port number are not used in this file, so

```
::89    localhost
::89    bluescript.com.ph
```

Should be

```
::1    localhost
::1    bluescript.com.ph
```

After this change either reboot, or from a command window launched "As Adminitrator" do

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

Comment: I still got same error: Do I need to change VirtualHost *:80 to 89?

Comment: Refresh the page, I added some info

Comment: Thanks. now its good! :), However is it possible to hide/remove this 8989 in http://bluescript.com.ph:8989 and remain http://bluescript.com.ph?

Comment: No, not unless you use the default port 80